# Gems not appearing in JRuby gem list (succesfully installed)

Tags: rubygems, jruby

This question has two parts:

1. I installed JRuby using rvm today, install went fine.  I also
   have Ruby 1.9.3 installed on my system.  Is there an easy way to
   re-install the same gems I have in 1.9.3 into JRuby?
2. I attempted to install the json gem in JRuby.  First I switched from
   my default Ruby to JRuby by doing: `rvm jruby` (and checked to make
   sure I was using jruby by doing `rvm current`).  Then I did `jruby
   -S gem install json`.  It sucessfully installed:

   ```
   Successfully installed json-1.7.5-java
   ```

   But when I do `gem list` (or `jruby -S gem list`), I just get the gems that were installed when JRuby was installed.  I tried exiting the terminal, and doing gem list again, but it still does not show.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

## UPDATE

I found that the gempath in gem env is not the same as where the gems are being installed.  How do I add another new gempath to this list (in bash)? **or preferably** how do I ensure the gems are being installed in the correct GEM PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I used rvm to install jruby, I used this to install the gem in the correct location:

```
sudo rvm jruby do gem install json
```